# Find a match of any string within an array in another string with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, strpos

I'm matching a set of strings against a string and if one of the strings of the array appears in the string, then some text should show up.

In practice: I would like to include a menu only on specific pages. So I include a PHP snippet in my template and the menu should show up when one of the defined page names appears in the URL. Currently I use this code which works:

```
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

if (strpos($domain, '/page1.php') !== false) {
        echo 'Text',
}
elseif (strpos($domain, '/page2.php') !== false) {
        echo 'Text',
}
elseif (strpos($domain, '/page3.php') !== false) {
        echo 'Text',
}
elseif (strpos($domain, '/page4.php') !== false) {
        echo 'Text',
};
```

Is it possible to condense the code to make it more efficient rather than repeating for each page an elseif line. I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$string = array('page1.php', 'page2.php', 'page3.php', 'page4.php');

if (strpos($domain, $string) !== false) {
        echo 'Text',
};
```

Any suggestions?

Philip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$string = array('page1.php', 'page2.php', 'page3.php', 'page4.php');
foreach($string as $str){
   if (strpos($domain, $str) !== false) {
    echo 'Text',
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If each page has to generate a different results then you should use `switch()`, and if all the results are the same then just create an `array('page1.php', 'page2.php', 'page3.php', 'page4.php');` and use `in_array()` ...

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$string = array('page1.php', 'page2.php', 'page3.php', 'page4.php');

foreach ($string as $key => $value) {
  if (strpos($domain, $value) !== false) {
    echo 'Text',
  }
}
```